# I cannot scrape anything with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im using BeautifulSoup to scrape some web contents.

Im learning with this example code,but I always get a "None" response.

Code:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.velocidadcuchara.com/2011/08/helado-platano-light.html').read())

post = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'topmenucontainer'})

print post
```

Any idea what Im doing wrong ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think *you* are doing anything wrong.

It is the second script tag that is confusing BeautifulSoup. The tag looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
var arVersion = navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")
var version = parseFloat(arVersion[1])

function fixPNG(myImage) 
{
    if ((version >= 5.5) && (version < 7) && (document.body.filters)) 
    {
       var imgID = (myImage.id) ? "id='" + myImage.id + "' " : ""
       var imgClass = (myImage.className) ? "class='" + myImage.className + "' " : ""
       var imgTitle = (myImage.title) ? 
                     "title='" + myImage.title  + "' " : "title='" + myImage.alt + "' "
       var imgStyle = "display:inline-block;" + myImage.style.cssText
       var strNewHTML = "<span " + imgID + imgClass + imgTitle
                  + " style=\"" + "width:" + myImage.width 
                  + "px; height:" + myImage.height 
                  + "px;" + imgStyle + ";"
                  + "filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader"
                  + "(src=\'" + myImage.src + "\', sizingMethod='scale');\"></span>"
       myImage.outerHTML = strNewHTML     
    }
}
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

but BeatifulSoup seems to think it is still in a comment or something and includes the rest of the file as content of the script tag.

Try:

```
print str(soup.findAll('script')[1])[:2000]
```

and you'll see what I mean.

If you remove the CDATA then you should find the page parses correctly:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(
    urllib2.urlopen('http://www.velocidadcuchara.com/2011/08/helado-platano-light.html')
    .read()
    .replace('<![CDATA[', '').replace('<!]]>', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something weird with your HTML. BeautifulSoup tries its best, but sometimes it just can't parse it.

Try moving the first `<link>` element inside the `<head>`, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use lxml lib.

[lxml article](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/10/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library/)

```
from lxml.html import parse
doc = parse('http://java.sun.com').getroot()
post = doc.cssselect('div#topmenucontainer')
```